# Does it require less electricity to hold a zero bit in RAM than a one bit?

Tags: memory, encoding, energy-saving

Someone I know posited an idea that I instinctively think (know?) cannot be true, but I can't seem to figure out how to explain why not.  The idea is based on the assumption that more electricity must be used to store a bit value of `1` in RAM than a `0`.  If that assumption is true (I'm not sure that it is), then the idea is that we could lessen the electricity drawn by systems if we hyper-optimized every encoding system such that less commonly stored values are assigned the heavier byte values (heavier in the sense of having more bits set to 1).

I'm not even sure that's a sense-making endeavor, even if the initial assumption were true.  This would all certainly be moot, though, if someone could explain that the byte value `x00` does not require less electricity to store in RAM than `xFF`.

Comment: Note: Your question includes an error: "bigger values" does not necessarily means that more bits are set to 1: `0x7F` has 7 bits set `0x80` is greater but has only one bit set. Hence an optimization would get really complicated.

Comment: You could invent a system where the current paradigm would be inverted, a sort of "anti-byte", where "0" would be used for a "yes", and "1" would be used for a "no"...

Comment: Also note: Some memory components read a "1" in the unprogrammed state (i.e. when holding no charge) so they would need the opposite approach. By trying to reduce the number of "1" bits (or "0" bits for that matter), there must still be a way to store all possible values, thus needing more bits to store the same amount of data, kind of defeating the purpose.

Comment: @Didier, the way digital electronics work, signals are often "active low", i.e. a low voltage on one of the pins of a device activates a function, while a high voltage inhibits it. Electronics do not care if "high voltage" represents "1" or "yes" or exactly the opposite.

Comment: @Robert - Yes, I misspoke; it was not my intention to invoke "greater" in that sense, more in the sense of "heavier" where the greatest byte is 1111-1111, but the next greatest ones would be 1111-1110, 1111-1101, 1111-1011, 1111-0111, 1110-1111, 1101,1111, 1011-1111 and 0111-1111.  All of those bytes would be tied for second greatest.

Comment: It's sad to note how incapable of taking a joke some of you guys are here... The only way to do what the OP implies would be a complete absence of power consumption for one state of a bit, be it "0" or "1", it doesn't matter, so that when that state was attained, no electrical power would be consumed at all. This hasn't even been achieved in regular HDDs when storing data in ferrite particles, and we're talking data storage here, not active data in RAM, so I took the OP's question to be rhetorical, and answered in kind... Maybe in quantum computing, or photon-based computing, could it be done?

Comment: Don't forget that DRAM (which is typically "_everywhere_" these days, aside from the smallest embedded equipment) needs to be refreshed... so it stands to reason that one bit value might take more energy to read and re-assert than the other... but I couldn't tell you which, and I suspect it would be an incredibly small figure - possibly in the order of nano/femto Joules difference or less between a single `1` vs a `0`(?)... scale that up to 16-32 GB of RAM and you might make a measurable difference, perhaps in the order of milli Joules.. (**note: all figures are guesses**).

Comment: [Here's a write up from 2018](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2018/ph240/jiang2/) that suggests that storing a single bit on an SSD comes to approx 0.35 femto Joules (x10^-15) vs. a HDD at ~100 fJ (or ~285 times higher)... so my guesses may be an order of magnitude or two off. No mention of a `1` vs a `0` though.

Comment: [This paper](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~saugatag/papers/18sigmetrics_vampire.pdf) suggests that power consumption strongly depends on the data value being read or written (see Section 8, point 2). There are some words and figures on power consumption during refresh too!

Comment: [This question is almost as bad as your last one](https://superuser.com/questions/1548972/why-optimizing-a-system-to-use-bytes-with-fewer-1-values-will-not-save-electrici)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Glad to see I've improved!  In any case, as I got no substantive explanation for what was wrong with the last one, I tried a more focused approach that zeroed in on a precise technical question.  If you want to help with this, perhaps you could offer an opinion on what needs improving before I post another question to replace this one.

Comment: @Attie - Those are extremely interesting contributions.  If I can figure out how to rephrase this to appease the mod, and if you want to take the time to draw a conclusion from your sources, I think you might have a great answer.  If I understood the applicable sections of that paper correctly, it seems there may be some minor current differences in a few DRAM operations, but not all.  I would think such minor differences would be better handled in the world of chip engineering, not in optimizing, say, Unicode, to prefer fewer 1-bit-heavy values.

Comment: I think that this question would be much better suited to the [EE partner site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Trie to refine the question though - discard the "_what if_" and theoreticals about optimising (as I think you hinted in your other question, it would be very impractical to do such optimisation...) - focus on the technical question of "_does it use more energy to store/maintain a logic `1` or `0` in DRAM?_"... SRAM, MRAM, etc... will have even less of a difference to store, and likely nearly no difference (SRAM) or actually no difference (MRAM) to maintain the value.